# Array of Reminder in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

how to declare "Name" of array of Reminder?

I declare the array of reminder using syntax:

```
reminder = new Reminder[10];
```

In many tutorial, to declare "Name" of Reminder using syntax:

```
reminder = new Reminder(name)
```

how to combine that two?

UPDATE:

"Name" here is mean name of reminder, works like an ID in Windows Phone

Comment: looks like one tutorial is c# and the other is vb.net, your array does not have a name property just what you declared it as.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "Name" is name of reminder, like an ID

Comment: I still stand by my comment, an array does not have an ID it is a collection of objects. Please share the links that you are referencing in your question

Comment: here, this is one of tutorial I follow http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-reminder-depth

Comment: Ok a reminder is a Windows Phone object that does have a name property, your array is just a collection of reminders you have to add the name to each individual reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax meant to "instantiate" an empty array of `Reminder` with size 10 and assign it to variable named `reminder` :

```
reminder = new Reminder[10];
```

And this one meant to create single `Reminder` instance and assign it to a `Reminder` variable (not array) named `reminder` :

```
reminder = new Reminder(name);
```

"*How to combine that two*" is actually not a clear requirement. Anyway this demonstrate on how to create `Reminder` instances and store them in each element of the array *based on link posted in comment* :

```
reminder = new Reminder[10];
for(int i = 0; i < reminder.Length; i++)
{
    string reminderName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    reminder[i] = new Reminder(reminderName);
}
```